# Как достать элементы из JSON в виде массива?

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

```
"0": {},
"Guys": {
    "0": null,
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mort",
        "lat": "443",
        "lng": "23",
        "status": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Sam",
        "lat": "45",
        "lng": "324",
        "status": "0"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Peter",
        "lat": "546",
        "lng": "24",
        "status": "1"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Adam",
        "lat": "643",
        "lng": "22",
        "status": "1"
    },
    "5": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Bonzo",
        "lat": "2423",
        "lng": "2344",
        "status": "0"
    },
    "6": {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "hjghj",
        "lat": "657",
        "lng": "66",
        "status": "1"
    },
    "7": {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "h",
        "lat": "44",
        "lng": "44",
        "status": "0"
    },
    "8": {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "h",
        "lat": "6576",
        "lng": "6",
        "status": "1"
    },
```

Как вытащить все элементы из `Guys`(в моем случае их `8`) в виде `JSON` массива.
Т.е... простейший, может даже и глупый пример: чтобы `JSONArray.length` возвращало восемь. И так, чтобы можно было доставать их в цикле и, например, выводить в `List View`.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я еще не практиковал GSON (с ним удобнее) но все же:

***1. Создайте модель Guy:***

```
public class Guy {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double lat, lng;
    private boolean status;

    public Guy(long id, String name, double lat, double lng, boolean status){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.status = status;
    }

    //getters and setters
    //Alt + Insert

}
```

***2. Парсинг JSON***

```
public List<Guy> parseGuys(JSONObject json) {
    List<Guy> guys = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject guysJSON = json.getJSONObject("Guys");
    Iterator<?> keys = guysJSON.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        Object value = guysJSON.get((String)keys.next());
        if (value != null && value instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject guyJSON = (JSONObject) value;
            long id = guyJSON.getLong("id");
            String name = guyJSON.getString("name");
            double lat = guyJSON.getDouble("lat");
            double lng = guyJSON.getDouble("lng");
            boolean status = (1 == guyJSON.getInt("status"));
            guys.add(new Guy(id, name, lat, lng, status));
        }
    }
    return guys;
}
```

***3. Создание адаптера (я предпочитаю 'RecyclerView')***

```
public class GuysAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GuysAdapter.GuyHolder> {

    private List<Guy> guys;

    private class GuyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.guy_item_name);
        }

        public void bind(Guy guy) {
            tv_name.setText(guy.getName());
        ]
    }

    public GuysAdapter(List<Guy> guys) {
        this.guys = guys;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.guy_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GuyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(guys.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return guys.size();
    }
}
```

***4. Создание адаптера***

```
RecyclerView guysList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.guysList);
guysList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
GuysAdapter adapter = new GuysAdapter(parseGuys(json));
guysList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: "Guy guy = " - не дописали. Сюда получается надо дописать new Guys (...параметры для конструктора...), так?\

Comment: Я просто боялся что пока я пишу другие уже ответ весь набросали ;)

Comment: Проверили? я просто без IDE написал

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. А как к эту листу обратиться. Точнее как к его элементам обратиться? Или можно вместо листа использовать ассоциативный массив?

Comment: Можно и массив, но нужно знать длину, а в JSON я смотрю есть и null-ы. Потребуется больше манипуляций

Comment: Пример обращения к элементам листа можно найти в адаптере: вместо array[position] нужно list.get(position)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, у вас `Guys` в json'е - это словарик, а не массив.
С помощью jackson можно так:

```
ObjectMapper JsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode node = JsonMapper.readValue(testStr, ObjectNode.class);

// получаем словарь парней
Map<String, ObjectNode> guys = JsonMapper.readValue(node.get("Guys"), new TypeReference<HashMap<String,ObjectNode>>() {});

// преобразуем в массив
ObjectNode[] guysArray = guys.values().toArray(new ObjectNode[guys.size()]);
```

Подключение jackson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Можно гораздо проще через @JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter + Map<String, Guy>

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у вас есть модель:

```
public class Guy {

    public long id;
    public String name;
    public double lat, lng;
    public boolean status;

}
```

Так же есть класс:

```
public class GuysList {

    public final Map<String, Guy> guys = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> any() {
        return guys;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        guys.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Теперь вам Jackson с легкостью разберет (если вы берете json из сети - посмотрите на Retrofit + Jackson):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
GuysList data = mapper.readValue(testStr, GuysList.class);
// теперь можно вызвать data.values() для получения списка или data.size() для количества
```